# Python/django inherit from 2 classes

Tags: python, django, django-users

In my django project I have 2 variations of users. One subclasses User class from django.auth and second uses almost the same fields but is not a real user (so it doesn't inherit from User). Is there a way to create a FieldUser class (that stores fields only) and for RealUser subclass both FieldUser and User, but for FakeUser subclass only FieldUser ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sure, I've used multiple inheritance in django models, it works fine.

sounds like you want to setup an abstract class for FieldUser:

```
class FieldUser(models.Model):
    field1 = models.IntegerField()
    field2 = models.CharField() #etc
    class Meta:
        abstract=True #abstract class does not create a db table

class RealUser(FieldUser, auth.User):
    pass #abstract nature is not inherited, will create its own table to go with the user table

class FakeUser(FieldUser):
    pass #again, will create its own table
```

Comment: superb ! That's what I was trying to achieve !

Comment: and some docs with that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#multiple-inheritance